# c++, truncate a char array

Tags: c++

I'm working on a project where I have a Time class and I need to format the time.

```
void Time::FormatTime(char *string, unsigned int max_string_len) {
    ostrstream fd;
    ft << hour << ":" << minutes;
    cout << ft.str() << endl;    
}
```

The user passes in a pointer to their string and the max length of the string and I need to check that the time string isn't longer than max_string_len and if it is, then truncate it. I'm not sure how to do the truncation as it's been awhile since I've written any C++.

I'd like to not use the STL if possible.

Thanks

Comment: If you more or less know that the time is going to take 5 characters, why not assert that the length is enough? What good does the truncated time representation do you?

Comment: Practice at not overflowing strings, apparently…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always use `strncpy()` to safely truncate a string into a `char[N]`.

```
void Time::FormatTime(char *str, unsigned int max_string_len) {
    if ( max_string_len == 0 ) return;
    ostringstream ft; // strstream is obsolete, use stringstream
    ft << hour << ":" << minutes;
    strncpy( str, ft.str().c_str(), max_string_len );
    str[ max_string_len - 1 ] = 0;
}
```

Comment: @Manuel: Fine, although I think that's silly. Note that `snprintf` does not include the terminating byte in its limit argument, so passing 0 to this function would be like passing -1 to `snprintf`.

Comment: oops, scratch that about `snprintf`.

Answer (score 2):

This does what you want:

```
 void Time::FormatTime(char *string, unsigned int max_string_len) {
      ostrstream fd;
      ft << hour << ":" << minutes;
      std::string str = ft.str();
      str.resize(max_string_len);
      strcpy(string, str.c_str());
 }
```

**EDIT:** I've updated my code thanks to the helpful feedback of potatoswatter and quanmrana.

Comment: This is the most straightforward way to do it. Short and simple.

Comment: -1: strlen(string) might be undefined if max_string_len is 0.

Comment: `str.resize(n)` adjusts `str` to have `n` characters not including the terminating byte. `strcpy` copies `n` characters plus the terminating byte, which causes an overflow.

Comment: @Manuel: You should also rename the first parameter from `string` to something like `str` now that you're using the stl.  You don't want anything confused with `std::string`.

Answer (score 2):

```
if( str.length() > max_string_len ) 
{ 
    str = str.substr( 0, max_string_len );
}

strncpy( string, str.c_str(), max_string_len );
```

Answer (score 1):

If the first parameter can be modified then you can just place a 0 in the correct position to be a string terminator, however this is a fairly nasty (but fast) solution. Otherwise, you'll want to create a new array of characters and only copy over the correct number of characters, remembering to allocate an extra character for the zero terminator.

Answer (score 1):

I'm half guessing at what you want, but I think it's something like the following, where I'm assuming or changing:

- `ft` really should be `fd`
- I used an `ostringstream` object instead of an `ostrstream`
- `max_string_len` is the size of the destination buffer in characters (including the character that will hold the '\0' terminator)
- you're not really interested in the formatted string being sent to `std::cout`, but want it in the caller's provided buffer
- I changed the name of parameter `string` to `s` so it wouldn't be confused with the `std:string` type.

The code:

```
void Time::FormatTime(char *s, unsigned int max_string_len) {
    if (max_string_len == 0) {
        return;  // no buffer, bail out
    }

    std::ostringstream fd;

    fd << hour << ":" << minutes;

    size_t len = fd.str().copy( s, max_string_len - 1);  // leave room for the null terminator

    s[len] = '\0';
}
```

If you really don't want any part of the STL, then the following C-styled code should do the trick:

```
void Time::FormatTime(char *s, unsigned int max_string_len) {

    snprintf( s, max_string_len, "%02u:%02u", hour, minutes);
}
```

It's simpler, but may C++ developers don't like using the `printf()` family because it's not typesafe.

Comment: Crud - I just noticed the desire to not use the STL - I'm using the STL here because the example given in the question uses it, and the tag says "C++"...  Post a comment if I should delete this answer, and if you want a pure C function, let's retag the question as just a C question.

Comment: I like your first little snippet, but I keep getting this error: "left of '.copy' must have class/struct/union"

Comment: The first snippet compiles just fine on VS2008 after adding `#include <sstream>`, declarations for `hour` and `minutes`, and correcting `max_string_len`.

Comment: Sorry about the `max_String_len` typo (now fixed).  I should have made clear that `std::ostringstream` requires a `#include <sstream>` and that I assumed that `hour` and `minutes` were members of the `Time` class (based on the original snippet).

Comment: -1: You need to pass `max_string_len-1` to `snprintf`, that code overflows.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: that's incorrect - `snprintf()` expects the size of the buffer - you don't need to 'hold back' a character for the terminator. From the standard: "If n is zero, nothing is written,
and s may be a null pointer. Otherwise, output characters beyond  the n-1st are discarded rather than being written to the array, and a null character is written at the end of the characters actually written into the array".

Answer (score 0):

From your requirements, you seem intent on writing C instead of C++, but I guess that's your business. For your specification, however, it appears that the right answer is `strftime()`.